# Ubuntu 20.04 - Browsers (Firefox & Chrome) Won't Use / Prioritize IPv4 Despite gai.conf Precedence - How can I prefer IPv4?

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, ipv6, ipv4

In /etc/gai.conf, I have the following:

```
label  ::1/128       0
label  ::/0          1
label  2002::/16     2
label ::/96          3
label ::ffff:0:0/96  4
precedence  ::1/128       50
precedence  ::/0          40
precedence  2002::/16     30
precedence ::/96          20
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

However, browsers Firefox, Chrome, and Chromium are ignoring these preferences and are using my IPv6 IP address for traffic rather than my IPv4 IP address.

Is there a way to get Firefox and all browsers to respect my prioritization?

I'd prefer to use IPv4 for all traffic unless something is only available via IPv6.  Reading the internet, it was said to modify gai.conf, which I did, but it doesn't appear to work.

Pinging google.com from the command line returns an IPv4 address, so it appears that some programs are respecting the `/etc/gai.conf` settings...

Anyone know?

Comment: What use case do you have for not letting it randomly choose between IPv4 and IPv6? Additionally, my ISP is IPv4 only and I have never encountered problems in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: https://forums.he.net/index.php?PHPSESSID=q5lv0ei89rplus57un3mdhecve&topic=4253.0  My ISP doesn't have IPv6 native support (Quantum Fiber), so I use an IPv4 tunnel thanks to Hurricane Electric (HE).  However, Google doesn't like traffic from HE, and I'm tired of having to fill out captchas, so I'd rather it default to using my ISP IPv4 address rather than the tunneled IPv6 address.

Comment: Is there an application that is stopping you from disabling IPv6?

Comment: Yeah, sometimes, I need to access IPv6 only services / addresses.  So, I still need IPv6, but rarely.